# How can I use latest features of C# v6 in T4 templates?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, t4

I'm trying to run a new T4 template in Visual Studio 2015. However it fails to compile at this line:

```
var message = $"Linked table '{linkedTable}' does not exist.";
```

The compiler reports that the '$' character is unexpected. This syntax should however be valid in C# v6, according to the new [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) feature guidelines.

Is there a way to make the T4 templating engine use the newer C# version, **other than to compile my code in an external library**?

**UPDATE:**

Here are the declaration elements for the file, as a reference:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".sql" #>
<#@ SqlModelDirective processor="SqlModelDirectiveProcessor" #>

<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model" #>
```

Apart from the `SqlModelDirective` element this is pretty standard I think.

Comment: Can you post the "rest" of the T4? The beginning usually has directives that define the language, linkage, etc.

Comment: Can you use other C# 6 features in T4? String interpolation doesn't work on Razor pages even though other features work. Perhaps it's the same bug in T4. Both Razor and T4 are converted to C# code before compiling. A bug in that conversion could cause the wrong C# code to be generated when using string interpolation

Comment: @Eris I updated the post.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ahhh, I think you're on to something. I'm out to lunch right now but I'll investigate on this as soon as I get back.

Comment: Also, when you say fails to compile, does it fail to generate code using the T4, or is the generated code not compiling?

Comment: @Eris, the OP's template generates SQL. The compiler error almost certainly occurs in the template itself

Comment: First step I would do is set `debug="true"`, but from what I've seen in other questions is that T4 generation is "locked" in at C#4. It might be possible to set `language="C#6.0"` and add the appropriate references, but I don't have the facilities to test at the moment.

Comment: @Eris It's the template code that fails to compile, not the code it generates (in fact it doesn't generate any right now).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use C# 6 in T4 templates right now as they don't use the latest compiler.

You can specify compiler options in the `compilerOption` attribute of the [template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586945(v=vs.120).aspxhttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586945(v=vs.120).aspx) directive. If the latest compiler was used, you could use:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" 
    compilerOptions="/langversion:6" #>
```

When I tried this I got the following error:

> Compiling transformation: Invalid option '6' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, 3, 4, 5 or Default

**UPDATE**

Found [this discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/272) on the ASP.NET repository on Github. Seems the ASP.NET team is looking to replace T4 with Razor (which is *not* a bad idea BTW). Wonder if @davidfowl has more info ;)

**UPDATE 2**

David Fowler [responded on Twitter](https://twitter.com/davidfowl/status/642155976724840448) - T4 uses CodeDom which hasn't been updated to use Roslyn yet. While there *is* a NuGet package with [replacement CodeDom providers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform), it works only on ASP.NET 4.x projects, not T4.

So no C# 6 in T4 for now.

Comment: I guess this means for the time being I must stick to `string.Format`... man, that hurts! Still, I got to learn about the `compilerOptions` attribute. It's something. Thank you so much!

Comment: This seems to be working now in VS2017 15.6.6, once you add the compiler options flag mentioned above. woo!

Answer (score 10):

You should upgrade to [Visual Studio 2015 Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx), released on March 30, 2016, which introduces such functionality. Under its “Other Changes”:

> Enhanced T4 text templates so that they now support C# 6.0.

However, the functionality is broken again in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

Comment: CTP is of size 5GB :O , it's like I'm download MSVS 2015 again :S , I thought it's just update of size around 20-50 mb :S

Comment: update 2 has arrived with the promised C# 6 in t4 https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx

Comment: @GwynBleidd: Thanks for the update. I've incorporated the new link into the answer.

Comment: Really? I'm using VS2015 Update 3 and C# 6 features *still* aren't supported in T4 templates.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work with VS2015 U3. Even with `compilerOptions` set to `/langversion:6` the T4 just won't compile.

Comment: @nathanchere: Confirmed; seems to be a regression bug in Update 3. I'm also experiencing another weird bug with T4 templates; hopefully they'll be patched in an update soon.

Comment: Same here with the annoying feature of it not working in T4 either. Come on VS!

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2017 (and probably 2015 too), adding the latest `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` nuget package to the project containing your T4 templates will enable the latest C# features such as interpolated strings. (I have just done this using Visual Studio 2017 15.6.2 and version 2.7.0 of the package).

Answer (score 0):

This was not working for me in Visual Studio 2019 so I resorted to creating a separate project that I referenced with an assembly directive.  Essentially the assembly is a class feature block